# How to solve "Failed to connect with local Steam Client process"?

Tags: nvidia, games, steam

I installed Ubuntu 23.04 for the first time. I want to start gaming on linux and the first game that I want to try is CS GO. I enabled proton experimental, steam is up to date and installed latest nvidia drivers.When I try to launch first it has to download vulkan shaders, which is take an hour or more. It doesn't meter if I let it download or skip but I get the same error all the time: FATAL ERROR: Failed to connect with local Steam Client process!

Please make sure that you are running latest version of the Stem Client updates using steam main menu:   Steam > Check to Steam Client Updates

[CS GO launchig error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvyy9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem after native csgo version made a silent crash and I decided launch it with proton. Then i checked [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/hcshkv/csgo_proton_fatal_error_failed_to_connect_with/) and saw this explanation: "Csgo doesn't work with proton because vac won't allow you to connect, it's not even a bug I think, it's the way valve wants"

So I took proton out of csgo launch properties and started native version again. AND IT WORKED. I advise you to try the same.